# multiple input field align in the same row

Tags: html, css, input-field

The default (with any style) for 2 input is already align in the same row, but I want the second field to be in fixed width and they are responsive.

```css
input, select {
    width:100%;
}
select {
    width:100px;
    float:right;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="rowWrap">
    <input type="datetime-local" class="datetime" name="datetime" value="" placeholder="Date - Time *" />
    <select class="pax">
        <option value="1">1 pax</option>
        <option value="2">2 pax</option>
        <option value="3">3 pax</option>
        <option value="4">4 pax</option>
        <option value="5">5 pax</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: you need both input box in single row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean, like the below? With the `select` being fixed width, you can then use `calc` to make the `input` take up the remaining space. `box-sizing:border-box` ensures sizing remains as anticipated.

```css
input,
select {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 20px;
}
input {
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
}
select {
  width: 100px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="rowWrap">
  <input type="datetime-local" class="datetime" name="datetime" value="" placeholder="Date - Time *" />
  <select class="pax">
    <option value="1">1 pax</option>
    <option value="2">2 pax</option>
    <option value="3">3 pax</option>
    <option value="4">4 pax</option>
    <option value="5">5 pax</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: ah, doesn't support in safari?

Answer (score 0):

try this replace bellow css :

```
input, select {
    width:80%;
    float: left;
}
select {
    width: 100px;float: left;

}
```